# Express app with PassportJS login throwing TypeError: req.session.touch is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, session-cookies, express-session

I am implementing login with passportjs in express application. It is throwing error. THe error originates from express-session module. I found that req.session.touch function actually exist. Yet it is throwing error.

```
{"severity":"ERROR","message":"TypeError: req.session.touch is not a function\n    
at ServerResponse.end (D:\\Work\\work\\Projects\\firebase-api-app\\functions\\node_modules\\express-session\\index.js:330:21)\n    
at Strategy.strategy.redirect (D:\\Work\\work\\Projects\\firebase-api-app\\functions\\node_modules\\passport\\lib\\middleware\\authenticate.js:333:13)\n    
at stored (D:\\Work\\work\\Projects\\firebase-api-app\\functions\\node_modules\\passport-oauth2\\lib\\strategy.js:285:14)\n    
at NullStore.store (D:\\Work\\work\\Projects\\firebase-api-app\\functions\\node_modules\\passport-oauth2\\lib\\state\\null.js:5:3)\n
```

My index.js file codes -
(I am using both cookie-session and express-session) If I remove the express-session, I get another error prompting me to express-session.

```
  const express = require("express");
  const morgan = require("morgan");
  const helmet = require("helmet");
  const multer = require("multer");
  const cors = require("cors");
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  require("dotenv").config();
  const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
  const express_session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const middlewares = require("./middlewares");

const passport = require("passport");
const passportSetup = require("./passport");

//Defining routes to the exact file where handling code is located...
const userRoute = require("./routes/users2");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth3");
const projectRoute = require("./routes/projects2");
const storiesRoute = require("./routes/stories2");

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express_session({ secret: 'SECRET' }));
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(
  cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
  credentials: true,
})
);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(
  cookieSession({ 
  name: "session", 
  keys: [process.env.COOKIET_KEY_1, process.env.COOKIET_KEY_2], 
  maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 100 })
);


const router = express.Router();
const path = require("path");


app.use("/auth", authRoute);    
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/projects", projectRoute);
app.use("/api/stories", storiesRoute);



exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);


app.listen(8800, () => {
  console.log("Backend server is running!");
});
```

Comment: I think `passport.session()` only works with `express-session` (hence the error that you get when not including it) so you can't (also) use `cookie-session`.

Comment: Can you pls post an answer with clear details, am also facing this issue. I am using `express-session` and I get this error with logout. Here is my logout function: @robertklep


router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  req.logout((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
  });
  res.json({ msg: "Logged out successfully" });
});

module.exports = router;